# Jquery menu how to toggle class when click outside element

Tags: jquery

I have this menu but I can't figure out how  to remove the 'show' class on single elements when I click on different element??
First 2 functions are for on hover when the screen width it's more than 739.And that's ok.But for the responsive part How can I close elements when I click on a different elements?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 739) {
        $('#mainmenu li').hover(
            function () {
                //mostra sottomenu
                $('ul', this).stop(true, true).delay(50).slideDown(100);

            },
            function () {
                //nascondi sottomenu
                $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
            });
    }
    else {
        $('#mainmenu li.drop1').click(
            function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                //mostra sottomenu
                $('#myDropdown').toggleClass("show");
            }
        );
        $('#mainmenu li.drop2').click(
            function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                //mostra sottomenu
                $('#myDropdown2').toggleClass("show");
            }
        );
        $('#mainmenu li.drop3').click(
            function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                //mostra sottomenu
                $('#myDropdown3').toggleClass("show");
            }
        );
        $('#mainmenu li.drop4').click(
            function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                //mostra sottomenu
                $('#myDropdown4').toggleClass("show");
            }
        );

    };
});
```

Comment: You could take a page out of the Bootstrap book and add a 'dropdown backdrop'...so if you open a dropdown, you would append a 'backdrop' to the body with a z-index less than that of the dropdown menu with style of `position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;opacity:0`. Then anytime the backdrop is clicked, you close all dropdown menus. Not exactly what you're looking for, but a far less frustrating solution programmatically.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap in my site.I mean maybe it's just matter of two line of codes more.But I'm not so skilled in jquery.Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

I solve with this code, although now I can't close the element when I click on it again^^

```
else {
    $(".drop").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#myDropdown:visible", $(this).siblings()).slideUp("fast");
        $("#myDropdown:visible", $(this)).slideUp();
        $("#myDropdown", this).slideDown();


    });
    $(document).on("click", function(){
$(".drop #myDropdown").slideUp();
});
```